# Calling a JavaScript function from shiny server

Tags: javascript, function, shiny, shinyjs

I want to call a javascript function, display in my case, from server.R with one parameter. The print statement below the call is getting executed, but the javascript function is not getting executed. Is this the right way of calling js function?

```
observe ({
    if (is.null(input$location))
      return()

      tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "datadisplay.js")
      tags$script(JS('display(today_trends))'))

      print(today_trends[1])
      })
}
```

My js file:

```
function disp(params) {
  var myWindow = window.open("");
  myWindow.document.write("New window");

}
```

I've also tried js$display(today_trends) this way, but I get an error: Attempt to apply non-function.

Modified js file:

```
shinyjs.display = function(params) {
      var myWindow = window.open("");
      myWindow.document.write("New window");
};
```

Comment: that cant work like that. Have a look at `shinyjs::runjs()`,...